# Javac on different path (linux system)

Tags: centos, javac

I was only curious as to why my system is acting like this. So I have a CentOS system (centos 6.7-x86_64) with java and javac installed. Now, I'm trying to push this command through the terminal:

```
find /root/nlp/wasp/wasp-2.0alpha -name '*.java' | xargs javac -O
```

But it's giving me an error saying:

> error: error reading /root/nlp/stanford/openIE/../models.jar

Now, my problem is that in my command, I've directed the system to find all java files under the /root/nlp/wasp.. directory, not anywhere near close to the /root/nlp/stanford directory.

Interesting enough, when I just run the command before the pipe, I get the correct results (i.e. - files in the path is specified).

```
find /root/nlp/wasp/wasp-2.0alpha -name '*.java'
```

So my questions are, why on earth is the system looking at: 1.) a .jar file when I asked for .java files and 2.) a file in the wrong directory specified?

I ended up just removing that .jar file in the other directory and everything seems to be OK. But for the life of me, I am curious!

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes in your `find` command, e.g. `find /root/nlp/wasp/wasp-2.0alpha -name "*.java" | xargs javac -O` ?

Comment: I just tried it but still no go.